# Why am I missing pages on Google Analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, utm-parameters

I'm new to GA and I'm trying to create a couple of UTM links to specific pages of my site. I can see that the integration is working as there are visits to the pages when I click on those pages. However, when I open my UTM link, nothing shows up on the realtime section, and today I've noticed that I don't even have a campaigns page in GA so that I can see the report. What am I missing here? It's more than just the campaign page too. I don't have drop-down information on the realtime section, or an audience section.

[image: image showing missing features]

Comment: Which version of GA did you install?  Universal or GA4?

Comment: hi @StephenOstermiller , I believe I installed GA4.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I have the same problem